# Update all existing records with computed value of another field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class UpdateBrowserLanguageInInsightsVisits < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    Insights::Visit.update_all("browser_language = Iso639[context[`browser`][`language`]]&.name")
  end
end
```

I want to update all existing records with computed value of another json field called "context"

How do I get reference to another field in table inside update_all?

Comment: need to use the proper SQL json query syntax something like ```Iso639 -> 'browser' -> 'language' -> 'name'```

Comment: can you help me with the sql query? @dbugger

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html